# Copy Album Art from One Song to Rest of Album

Tags: google-play-music

I'm uploading music and Google auto-detects some of the artwork, but not all of it. Is there a way to copy the detected artwork to all of the songs in the album?

Answer (score 0):

Easy! 
1. Select album with missing or incorrect cover art
2. Goto iTunes or other music app that contains that album with your desired cover, select or right click edit, select cover and drag to your desktop (or copy and paste on desktop)
3. Go back to google album with missing cover, right click and select edit, in the edit screen select the up arrow in the cover section and select the cover you placed on desktop, then save edit screen and voila: the cover is where it belongs, hurray!
4. This way associates all tracks with the same cover, easy!
Cheers